# How to get calendar when page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, datepicker

how to show the calendar when the page loads. like the following image.

[image]

I am able to get the calendar on click the input button, but now i want to load the calendar when the page loads and get the value user selected.

The following is the place where i have to get the calendar load when the page loads

```
<table width="100%">
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
            <div style="color: white; font-size: 14pt;">Daily Shipments</div>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"> Load the calendar here </div>

</table>
```

Please help me to get this done.

Best Regards.

Comment: So, how are you loading that calendar when the "input button is clicked"?

Comment: can't you use : `window.onload = function() { }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code that you are using to get the calender in `window.onload = function() { }`
That should do for you.

Comment: No, it did not help me, could you please give a sample if you don't mind

Comment: I dont have the code right now. You said you are having a code that returns you calender on click of a button. Just put that same code into this. window.onload = function() { // your code to show calender here }.